# SwiftUI Circle() decreases performance in List

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, list, swiftui

I've a list of video, the image of these video are loaded in async way. In the mosaic I can see the activity indicator if is still loading, after the image was loaded, I can see the image preview. I've added an icon with play button.

When I scroll the list, it is not fluid. I've tried to change all async process, but without success. After some time I've tried to delete the Circle() function and was exactly it to decreases the performance.

Even if I solved the issue by changing the icon, I'd like to know if also you have this problem with circle function. It sounds like SKShapeNode in sprite kit.

Bad performance:

```
ZStack {
   Circle()
       .fill(Color.white)
       .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
       .opacity(0.7)
    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
       .font(Font.system(size: 33))
       .opacity(0.7)
       .foregroundColor(.black)})
}
```

Good performance:

```
Image(systemName: "play.circle.fill")
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .opacity(0.7)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
```